# Not able to run C# application built with VS 2003

Tags: c#, .net, .net-1.1, visual-studio-2003

Hi I have just created an application with VS2003 targeting .Net framework 1.1.

I just can't run/launch this application as it fails to start .. following is the error I get:

[image]

When I select "No" for debugging it throws the following exception in the console.

> ```
> Unhandled Exception: System.TypeInitializationException: [Resource lookup failed
> ```
>
> - infinite recursion detected.  Resource name: TypeInitialization_Type] ---> Sy
>   stem.NullReferenceException: [Resource lookup failed - infinite recursion detect
>   ed.  Resource name: Arg_NullReferenceException]
>      at System.Resources.ResourceReader.StripVersionField(String typeName)
>      at System.Resources.ResourceReader.InitSafeToDeserializeArray()
>      at System.Resources.ResourceReader.ReadResources()
>      at System.Resources.ResourceReader..ctor(Stream stream, Hashtable table)
>      at System.Resources.RuntimeResourceSet..ctor(Stream stream)
>      at System.Resources.ResourceManager.CreateResourceSet(Stream store)
>      at System.Resources.ResourceManager.InternalGetResourceSet(CultureInfo cultur
>   e, Boolean createIfNotExists, Boolean tryParents)
>      at System.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(String name, CultureInfo cultur
>   e)
>      at System.Environment.GetResourceString(String key)
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture, Boolean useUserOverr
>   ide)
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..ctor(Int32 culture)
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo..cctor()
>      [Resource lookup failed - infinite recursion detected.  Resource name: Except
>   ion_EndOfInnerExceptionStack]
>      at System.Globalization.CultureInfo.get_UserDefaultUICulture()
>      at System.Threading.Thread.get_CurrentUICulture()

Same application if I build with VS 2005 or any other version it works fine.
I have tried to reinstall VS2003  and the Microsoft .NET version  1.1 but it does not help.  If I rename the  folder `C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v1.1.4322` Then the program runs fine(apparently  it falls back to higher version of .Net Runtime).

I am not able to figure out what changed in the system to trigger this  and how to fix this issue. Things were working fine till a few weeks ago. This is Win7 64 bit machine.

Comment: You can't run an application targeting an old runtime unless that runtime is installed on the machine. .NET 1.1 is **very** old, way beyond deprecated and won't be found on any machine unless you install it. The Visual Studio version has nothing to do with this

Comment: Why *did* you create an application using VS 2003 anyway? .NET 1.1 isn't supported any more and all current versions of Windows work just fine with the latest runtime versions

Comment: Thanks . agree it's quite old.  But  I do have Framework 1.1 installed  and the application was working fine till some time back.

Comment: "Same application if I build with VS 2005 or any other version it works fine." sounds like you solved your problem.

Comment: The exception mentions an infinite recursion while trying to retrieve the current culture. Did you change your machine's or user's locale? Did you change the application's UI culture explicitly to one not supported by 1.1 ? Have you done anything to change how the fallback culture is determined?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos , thanks for the clue .. I remembered some time back  I did change my regional settings in control panel to change the format to  English[India] .. the default I guess was  English[United States] ..  Now when I reverted it to English[United State] the problem got fixed.. Please add your suggestion as answer and I'll accept it as answer. Why this should matter is still not clear to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The exception call stack shows an error occurs when you try to retrieve the current UI culture. While the error message mentions an infinite recursion, the actual exception is a NullReferenceException. The most likely reason is that you changed the application's UI culture has changed to a culture that wasn't supported by .NET 1.1.

The UI culture matches the OS and/or user's display language by default, which means that you probably changed the OS display language recently.

The UI culture can also change through configuration settings or programmatically.

Comment: This is what was causing issue for me.  The format  in my regional settings was changed  to  "English [India]" . I had visited this in the past also  but ignored the '[India] ' part. I just checked the locale was still English.   Anyways  I  confirmed this now .. If I switch the format back to 'English[US]' .my console app works and  when I switch it to 'English[India] ' it does not work.  Note that my console based application is just a hello world application that is   doing  Console.WriteLine("Hello World").